# How to know weather ADF pipeline is in queue dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Each pipeline instance is running every one hour.

If my pipeline is in the queue I want to set an alert mail.

How to know whether ADF pipeline is in queue dynamically

Answer (score 0):

> How to know whether ADF pipeline is in queue dynamically

A pipeline run has different status during its lifecycle, the possible values of run status are listed below:

•   Queued

•   InProgress

•   Succeeded

•   Failed

•   Canceling

•   Cancelled

To monitor the pipeline run, add the following code:

```
# Monitor the pipeline run
time.sleep(30)
pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(
    rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
print("\n\tPipeline run status: {}".format(pipeline_run.status))
filter_params = RunFilterParameters(
    last_updated_after=datetime.now() - timedelta(1), last_updated_before=datetime.now() + timedelta(1))
query_response = adf_client.activity_runs.query_by_pipeline_run(
    rg_name, df_name, pipeline_run.run_id, filter_params)
print_activity_run_details(query_response.value[0])
```

You can get status using [status parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get#pipelinerun).
For more information follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically) document.

Comment: How to achieve this in ADF Pipeline, using Azure Portal.

Comment: You need to use AZURE FUNCTIONS. Refer this article https://mrpaulandrew.com/2019/11/21/get-any-azure-data-factory-pipeline-run-status-with-azure-functions/ by MRPAULANDREW